# Probability of flipping several weighted coins

Tags: probability

I have three coins, each with a probability of getting heads at 3%,5%,6%

If I flip all 3 coins once, what is the probability of getting at least 1 heads.

Is there some way to model problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the complement of this event E: No heads at all.

The probability of this event is $(1-0.03)*(1-0.05)*(1-0.06) = 1 - P(E)$

Hence $P(E) = 1 - (1-0.03)*(1-0.05)*(1-0.06) = 0.133790$